# Show text only if day of month is between 2 and 7

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I was wondering if it is possible in Reporting services 2005 to show a text if month's date is between the 2nd and 7th.

E.g. if today is the 3rd I will show 'TEXT', but if it is the 27th 'TEXT' will be invisible.

I get an error when using the expression as below:

```vb
=IIF(Day >= 2 Or Day < 7,'TEXT','')
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and tell us what you've tried so far, and what did and didn't work, why and where you got stuck, etc?

Comment: I have a report which should show word Draft between the 2nd and 7th of the month as the data needs to be tested before final version which is uploaded on the 7th. After the 7th the text box should not show the word DRAFT on the report.

Comment: The question is a bit better now, but you can still do a lot more without our help. Tell us what the error and actual message was, what you did to resolve the error, and why that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```
=IIF((Day(Now()) >= 2 ) and (Day(Now()) < 7) ,"TEXT","")
```

Comment: Thank you Developer this has worked and solved my issue I was not entering datetime in Day as parameter.